# DJango not finding static files, despite STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT set

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have just started learning DJango and am trying to use css file for my html template. As per the documentation, I have added the `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` to my `settings.py` file as follows:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

`BASE_DIR` is already set as follows:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

In the template, I am using the css file as follows

```html
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
```

and the `style.css` is present at location DJango_App/static, DJango_App being my project directory with the `manage.py` file. Still I am getting error

> "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1653

`DEBUG` is set to `True`

Directory structure is:

```
DJango_App
|->DJango_App
   |->(settings.py, urls.py, views.py, etc)
|->templates
   |->(html templates)
|->static
   |->style.css
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I suggest you check your settings in a shell (just do 'from django.conf import settings' in the shell and then look at your settings.BASE_DIR, DEBUG, settings.STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL. This will let you verify that they really are what you think they are.

Comment: @PaulWhipp I checked `STATIC_ROOT` it is pointing to the correct path

Comment: Can you update the question with directory structure...

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha updated

Comment: "python manage.py collectstatic" try this command and check if its pointing the correct directory.

Comment: @SurajBhandarkar it copied the admin files to the root location, but the problem isn't fixed

Comment: @ShantanuShinde This might bit off topic but have you placed <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}"> inside <head> tag ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**:

Looking at your directory structure above, your static files are not under a Django app. In that case, you should also set `STATICFILES_DIRS`, see:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS

Original:

Looks like you did not add the static url handler to `urlpatterns`.

[Serving static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/) require add to `urls.py`:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Can you post your `settings.py`?

Comment: just a note using `django.conf.urls.stati`, this is required `DEBUG=TRUE` in `settings.py` file and it is for developing environment. in production the DEBUG value should be false, your app might act differently in developing environment. see doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: @WeiJing you don't want Django serving your static assets in production.

Comment: true about in production Django app should NOT serve the static assets. My point is the changes might not working due to DEBUG value is different in developing environment and production environment. I used similar fix and it does not working for me when it rolls out to production.

Comment: Of course they won't, you should `collectstatic` and serve them by your http server

Answer (score 0):

How about try Django package [Whitenoise](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is easy to install and easy to use if you followed the instructions.

some simplified steps:

1. Collect static - make sure static files existing before install

   ```
    python manage.py collectstatic
   ```
2. Install the Whitenoise - this step depends how you managed the packages, update proper file(e.g. Pipfile or requirements.txt) and install. Below command just a example to install the package.

   ```
    pip install whitenoise
   ```
3. Update the static root in settings.py

   ```
    STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"
   ```
4. Add the following to your `MIDDLEWARE` in settings.py - from Whwitenoise docs, Whitenoise package should place after `django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware`

   ```
    `MIDDLEWARE = [
      'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
      'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', #add it here exactly after security middleware
      ...
    ]
   ```
5. now restart or rebuild the app to check whether it is working for you.

**Please check Whitenoise docs if you running into issue about installing the Whitenoise**([Whitenoise docs](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html#add-compression-and-caching-support))

a message for using `staticfiles_urlpatterns`:
**this only works when `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py` which means you should NOT use it for production environment.** see reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.urls.staticfiles_urlpatterns)